# Scala увеличить enum

Tags: scala

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно в Scala увеличить Enumeration на число?

```scala
object PracticalSkill extends Enumeration {
  type PracticalSkill = Value;
  val Novice, Advanced, Expert = Value;
}

var unitSkill = PracticalSkill.Advanced;
unitSkill += 1; // <-- Нужно что-бы получилось PracticalSkill.Expert так как он следующий
// Но чёт нечего толкового не могу загуглить...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `Enumeration` есть номера - `id`.

```
// извлечём номер Advanced
val advancedId = PracticalSkill.Advanced.id // 2

// следующий номер
val nextId = advancedId + 1 // 3

// по номеру достанем значение
val expert = PracticalSkill(nextId)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Надо будет запомнить, как это делается )